# Does anyone have a presentation about Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, presentations

Has anyone ever done a presentation on Stack Exchange or Stack Overflow?
Any of you has the leftover .pptx? or video?

Answer (score 5):

Joel Spolsky did a Google Tech Talk about Stack Overflow a while back.  [Learning from Stack Overflow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NWHfY_lvKIQ).